# How to toggle a control in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a added Graticule control in my OpenLayers map. Now I want to toggle this using a control button. This what I have written:

```
function init() { 
      graticuleCtl = new OpenLayers.Control.Graticule({
                    numPoints: 2, 
                    labelled: true,
                    displayInLayerSwitcher: true
      });

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {controls: []});
    map.addControl(graticuleCtl);
.
.
.
      var GraticuleCtl = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
            displayClass: "olGraticule",
            title: "Show Graticule",
            trigger: showGraticule});

        // Panel (toolbar)
        Panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
            defaultControl: DragPanCtrl
        });
        Panel.addControls([
            .
            .
            .
            .
            GraticuleCtl
        ]);
        map.addControl(Panel);
}

function showGraticule() {
   if (graticuleCtl.visible==true){  
       graticuleCtl.deactivate();
       return true;
       }   
   else if (graticuleCtl.visible==false){
       graticuleCtl.activate();
       return true;
       }
   else{}
}
```

But this works for once only, since the 'visible' property checks only for initial map load.

Answer (score 4):

`visible` is a parameter to the control.  You should however be checking the `active` attribute to see if the control is on or not, and then you can toggle your control with something else (link/button/etc).  [API here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.active).